# Neo4J - Simple "follower" graph

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I'm attempting to create a simple Twitter-esque "follower / friend" graph using Neo4J and Python. The graph would look something like

```
user_1 FOLLOWS user_2
user_1 FOLLOWS user_3
user_2 FOLLOWS user_1
```

After a day of reading I thought it best to dive straight in using the REST interface and, since I'm using Python, py2neo. Here is my code:

```
from py2neo import neo4j

def main():
    g = neo4j.GraphDatabaseService()

    # Create an index for our user nodes
    index = g.get_or_create_index(neo4j.Node, "user")

    # Create a single node, User 1
    node = index.get_or_create("user", "User_1", {"id": "User_1"})

    # Populate the graph with some more users just for testing
    nodes = []
    for user in ["User_2", "User_3", "User_4", "User_5"]:
        nodes.append( index.get_or_create("user", user, {"id":user}) )

    # Create a relationship between User_1 and User_2
    g.get_or_create_relationships( (node, "FOLLOWS", nodes[0]) )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, I'm using get_or_create_relationships to prevent duplicate relationships and when adding thousands of nodes I'm assuming this is going to incur some kind of overhead.

Using straight up "node.create_relationship_to(nodes[0], "FOLLOWERS")" seems to create duplicate relationships each time the script is run which for a graph db newbie confuses me slightly since the relationship is exactly the same.

The likelihood of creating duplicate relationships is very low but in the event it were to happen, would this cause issues with graph traversal? Should I be indexing my FOLLOWS index with some kind of unique function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use cypher `CREATE UNIQUE` to only create a FOLLOWs releationship if there is none existing, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-create-unique.html

Would that work?

Comment: So this would involve using a Cypher query rather than the py2neo "get_or_create_relationship"? If Cypher is the only way of doing this, seems like the REST interface is lacking a pretty fundamental feature :(

Comment: The rest interface also provides unique creation features, see http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-unique-indexes.html